# regsvcs-registered .NET class and dllhost

Tags: .net, com-interop, com+

Suppose there is defined ClassA which is 
1. COM visible ,
 
2. registered as COM+ out-of-process (using regsvcs)

There is also .NET code like

```
void f()
{
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
}
```

Is it right that when constructor of ClassA called , dllhost process started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating the class through .NET, not COM+, so the COM+ hosting process will not be involved.